# NaN value when adding lags using LSTM in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to analyze and predict sales based on a dataset, I have already tidied up my data, however, when I try to create lags, the monthly sales lags have values of NaN, what does this NaN mean? From the tutorial I'm referring, he doesn't have these NaN value, at least when he drops NaN values, he still have some output but in my case, I do not have anything when I drop NaN values...

```
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam 
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, train_test_split

#initiate plotly
pyoff.init_notebook_mode()

#read data
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\UOW\Yr3\FYP\Sample.csv", encoding='latin-1')

df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])

df.head(10)

# Drop empty cells
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
df.shape

# Drop unwanted columns
# Order ID, Ship Date, Ship Mode, Segment, Country, City, State, Postal Code, Region, Product ID, 
Category, Sub-Category, Product Name,

# Discount
df_sales = df.drop(['Order ID', 'Segment', 'Country', 'City', 'State', 'Postal Code', 'Region', 'Product ID', 'Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Product Name','Discount'], axis = 1)
df_sales.head(10)

# represent month in date field as its first day
df_sales['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['Order Date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df_sales = df_sales.groupby('Order Date').Sales.sum().reset_index()
df_sales

#plot monthly sales
 plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_sales['Order Date'],
        y=df_sales['Sales'],
    )
]
plot_layout = go.Layout(
         title='Montly Sales'
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)

# Create a new dataframe to model the difference
df_diff = df_sales.copy()

# Add previous sales to the next row
df_diff['Prev_Sales'] = df_diff['Sales'].shift(1)

# Drop the null values and calculate the difference
df_diff = df_diff.dropna()
df_diff['diff'] = (df_diff['Sales'] - df_diff['Prev_Sales'])

df_diff.head(10)

#plot sales diff
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_diff['Order Date'],
        y=df_diff['diff'],)]

plot_layout = go.Layout(
        title='Montly Sales Difference')

fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)

#create dataframe for transformation from time series to supervised
df_supervised = df_diff.drop(['Prev_Sales'],axis=1)

#adding lags
for inc in range(1,13):
    field_name = 'lag_' + str(inc)
    df_supervised[field_name] = df_supervised['diff'].shift(inc)

#drop null values
#df_supervised = df_supervised.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)***

df_supervised
```

then I the output I get is

Order Date  |  Sales  |  diff  |  lag_1  |  lag_2  |  lag_3  |  lag_4  |  lag_5  |  lag_6  |  lag_7 
 |  lag_8  |  lag_9  |  lag_10  |  lag_11  |  lag_12

1     2019-02-01  |  333904.9556  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN 
 |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

2     2019-03-01  |  361431.8218  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN 
 |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

3     2019-04-01  |  359930.1225  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN 
 |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

4     2019-05-01  |  348999.4696  |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN 
 |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

5     2019-06-01  |  372904.5441  |  23905.0745  |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662 
 |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

6     2019-07-01  |  372936.2013  |  31.6572  |  23905.0745  |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

7     2019-08-01  |  328648.3505  |  -44287.8508  |  31.6572  |  23905.0745  |  -10930.6529  | 
 -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

8     2019-09-01  |  371825.2898  |  43176.9393  |  -44287.8508  |  31.6572  |  23905.0745  | 
 -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

9     2019-10-01  |  363781.0459  |  -8044.2439  |  43176.9393  |  -44287.8508  |  31.6572 |  23905.0745 
 |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN
|  NaN  |  NaN  |  NaN

10    2019-11-01  |  336836.8240  |  -26944.2219  |  -8044.2439  |  43176.9393  |  -44287.8508  | 
 31.6572  |  23905.0745  |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN 
 |  NaN

11    2019-12-01  |  374106.0722  |  37269.2482  |  -26944.2219  |  -8044.2439  |  43176.9393 
  |  -44287.8508  |  31.6572  |  23905.0745  |  -10930.6529  |  -1501.6993  |  27526.8662  |  -30136.6174  |  NaN  |  NaN

If I uncomment out this code : `df_supervised = df_supervised.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`
it will show an output of nothing but the titles

Order Date  |  Sales  |  diff  |  lag_1  |  lag_2  |  lag_3  |  lag_4  |  lag_5  |  lag_6  |  lag_7 
 |  lag_8  |  lag_9  |  lag_10  |  lag_11  |  lag_12

Anyone can help me with this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: What’s the output you want?

Comment: Hi I actually solved this! thanks!!!

Comment: @zzzTeee how did you solve this? Did you get a good performance out of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN refers to Not A Number.

It is usual to have a NaN when using lag times.

You should try to fill the NaNs instead of dropping them if you want to retain your data.

E.g. `df.fillna(0)`

You can start by having a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much! However when I find the score when using the entire dataset, it gives me another NaN...